# Finding the next empty cell in a a colunm

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with several hundred entries per worksheet, & I have code to find the next free cell in a column. The code works on one sheet, but not the other. I know it is something simple but I can't figure out is wrong.

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each cell In ws.Columns(1).Cells
     If Len(cell) = 0 Then cell.Select: Exit For
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `code works on one sheet, but not the other` and your code reads `Set ws = ActiveSheet` Guessing button is only on one sheet so...

Comment: Are you aware that you can just go to cell A1 and press `Ctrl+[Down Arrow]` to find the next empty cell in column A? No need for VBA. Just Key Presses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a module find the next blank cell in a row. Here is the code`Sub Macro_FIND_NEXT_BLANK_SPACE()
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1)) Then
   ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Else
   ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select
End If
End Sub`
I then wrote the code to run the sub command. `Private Sub CommandButton14_Click()
Call Macro_FIND_NEXT_BLANK_SPACE
End Sub`
I would like to thank the group for their assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to "remember" the last empty cell that you found on the previous click:

```
Public iROW As Long

Sub CommandButton_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each cell In ws.Columns(1).Cells
    If cell.Row > iROW Then
         If Len(cell) = 0 Then
            cell.Select
            iROW = cell.Row
            Exit For
         End If
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

An alternative would be to use `Find()` and `FindNext()`

Comment: I am closer to a solution. findwindow & Gary's Student, I want to thank you for your assistance. You got me thinking about how to approach the issue. I have placed the code in a module & then wrote code to run the sub from a command button. When I run the sub, I get a syntax error on this line of code `Call Sub Macro_FIND_NEXT_BLANK_SPACE` COuld you explan what I am doing wrong & how to correct it.

Comment: Here is an answer that works `Private Sub CommandButton#_Click()
Call Macro_FIND_NEXT_BLANK_SPACE
End Sub`  The above code runs a module. `Sub Macro_FIND_NEXT_BLANK_SPACE()
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1)) Then
   ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Else
   ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select
End If
End Sub`